# Failed to calculate checksum of ref

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.10.2-slim-bullseye

# Set environment variables
ENV PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code

# Install dependencies
COPY /home/michael/PycharmProjects/django_project/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy project
COPY /home/michael/PycharmProjects/django_project/ .
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  pcask:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
  db:
    image: postgres:15
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
      - postgres_dumpdata:/var/lib/dumpdata/
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  postgres_dumpdata:

networks:
  routing:
    name: routing
    external: true
```

**Problem**

```
michael@michael:~/PycharmProjects/django_project/docker_files/pcask$ sudo docker compose up --build
[+] Building 1.5s (9/9) FINISHED                                                
 => [pcask internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                 0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 423B                                       0.0s
 => [pcask internal] load .dockerignore                                    0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                            0.0s
 => [pcask internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.10.2-sl  1.3s
 => [pcask internal] load build context                                    0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                            0.0s
 => [pcask 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.10.2-slim-bullseye@sha256  0.0s
 => CACHED [pcask 2/5] WORKDIR /code                                       0.0s
 => ERROR [pcask 3/5] COPY /home/michael/PycharmProjects/django_project/r  0.0s
 => CACHED [pcask 4/5] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt                 0.0s
 => ERROR [pcask 5/5] COPY /home/michael/PycharmProjects/django_project/   0.0s
------
 > [pcask 3/5] COPY /home/michael/PycharmProjects/django_project/requirements.txt .:
------
------
 > [pcask 5/5] COPY /home/michael/PycharmProjects/django_project/ .:
------
failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref cbba007b-59ed-412e-8cd4-90c94ea98a1e::lq17qgdoi8v4wutiencqcws4a: "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/django_project": not found
```

But I have used an absolute path in order to avoid any misinterpretation. And double-checked the path:

[image]

What can I try next?

Comment: `COPY` paths are _always_ relative to the `build:` directory, even if they look like absolute paths.  (And if you try to step out of that directory `COPY ../...` it is ignored.)

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: This question seems to be well researched. However, in common with many of your questions, it rather feels that you're passing the problem to volunteers, rather than demonstrating that you know the project is still yours to do. The language is still rather needy. You may find these resources helpful: [No Fluff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-like-greetings-signatures-thanks-etc-when-editin); [Asking Confident Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions).

Comment: Also worth reading: [Why is "Can Someone Help Me" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1):

All COPY command must refer to files present in the build context, that is the directory where you Dockerfile is located.

Indeed you should copy all needed files in the Dockefile directory.